# Creating onClick event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a table and render some rows with the ability to have a "hidden" row.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return(
            <tr>
                <td colSpan="8"> I am a child that can be hidden!</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
})


var CreateRows = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {childVisible: true}
    },

    render: function(){
        var rows = this.props.people.map(function(row, i){
            return (
                <tr key={i} onClick={this.onClick}>      
                    <td>{row['id']}</td>
                </tr>
                {
                    this.state.childVisible
                    ? <Child />
                    : null
                }
            )
        })
        return (
            <tbody>
                {rows}
            </tbody>
        )
    },

    onClick: function(){
        this.setState({childVisible: !this.setstate.childVisible})
    }
 });
```

I am calling `CreateRows` in another component and sending it some data:

```
render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ChangeRowCount updatePeople = {this.updatePeople}/>
                <table>
                    <CreateColumns columns={this.state.table_columns} />
                    <CreateRows people = {this.state.people}/>
                </table>
            </div>
        )   
    }
```

I realize my issue is that when I create the variable `rows` I'm including the function `onClick()` but it can't "see" it and getting this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClick' of undefined(…)`

Any thoughts on how I can include the onClick() function to show/hide the `Child` component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

youre seeing this error because you're calling `this.onClick` inside of the map function.
you need to set the context of the map function by passing `this` in as the second argument

```
    var rows = this.props.people.map(function(row, i){
        return (
            <tr key={i} onClick={this.onClick}>      
                <td>{row['id']}</td>
            </tr>
            {
                this.state.childVisible
                ? <Child />
                : null
            }
        )
    }, this)
```

see the `thisArg` section from [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the map function

Comment: Ahh ok. Also, I'm getting `Unexpected token (133:16)(…)` which is pointing at the {this.state.child.Visible}...any idea on that one?

Comment: I'll mark this as correct in 4 min when I it will let me.

Comment: you can only return one thing anyway, so the tr and ternary statement need to be wrapped in a single element. i'm not sure what the error is coming from but if i had to guess its just do to the formatting. if you collapse that to a single line does it still give you the error

Comment: Ok, I figured that part out, but back to the `script_2.js:154 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childVisible' of undefined(…)` issue...I'll update my question